# what is wso2 identity

Tags: wso2, identity, wso2-identity-server

Can someone explain, what is wso2 identity and using ?

i not found a explain in the web,

only:

WSO2 Identity Server enables enterprise architects and developers to improve customer experience by reducing identity provisioning time, guaranteeing secure online interactions, and delivering a reduced single sign-on environment. The WSO2 Identity Server decreases identity management and entitlement management administration burden by including role base access control (RBAC) convention, fine-grained policy based access control, and SSO bridging.

Answer (score 2):

WSO2 Identity Server is an open source Identity and Entitlement server. It supports following standards.

- OpenID
- OAuth 1.0a/2.0
- XACML 2.0/3.0
- SAML2
- WS-Trust/STS
- SCIM
- XKMS
- User Management
- Connectors to AD/LDAP

Comment: what is a "Identity" and Entitlement server ? why use ?

Answer (score 1):

What is WSO2 IS:

The WSO2 Identity Server is implemented to solve identity problems; WSO2 Identity Server is fully open source. It undergoes continuous improvements and enhancements with each new release, to address new business challenges and customer expectations. The main focus of WSO2 IS is an individual’s identity needs to be validated across various applications and devices; this should be taken in a secure manner that will ensure security as well as speed of access and ease of use.

Using WSO2 IS:

WSO2 IS provides secure identity management for enterprise web applications, services, and APIs. WSO2 IS guarantee secure online interactions and it decreases the identity management and entitlement management. The Identity Server enables you to create, maintain and terminate user accounts along with user identities across multiple systems including Cloud applications. When there are multiple applications that require authentication, users should be able to log in at one place and still have seamless access to all the other applications. Furthermore, it has an improved approach for federation. (There is a centralized identity called service provider that is “n to n” relationship. There is a “1 to n” relationship from a federation partner to consumer services and a “1 to n” relationship from consumer service to federation partners; it leads to greater efficiency.)  WSO2 IS has the ‘Jaggery’ user interface for end users. WSO2 IS has end user view as well to manage profiles to recover accounts and to handle authorization.

Answer (score 0):

it's an identity management server , a simple example of wso2 identity is oAuth Identity System